# How can I secure a Batch file that locks the computer?

Tags: batch-file

Okay, so I have a lock script that locks my computer, but using alt + tab gets around this. Is there a way to stop this? Also, entering nothing and pressing enter gets around it too.

The code uses 2 windows, one to keep the window open when it is closed

```
@echo off
powershell -command "& { $x = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application; $x.minimizeall() }"
tskill explorer
tskill explorer
:a
start /w Lock.bat
goto a
```

and the other is the actual lock script:

```
@echo off
mode 35,10
cls
color a
title Locked by %username%
echo What is the password?
set /p password=
if %password%==password goto end
goto fail

:end
start explorer
exit

:fail
exit
```

Is there a way to stop these from happening?

### Edit

I solved the blank issue by using

```
If [%password%]==[] goto fail
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a screensaver feature that asks you to enter your password to resume.

You could probably launch that in a batch file.